# connected cells in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

is there a way in Excel to make calls "connected"?

as in: if I move the value of once cell how can the other cell move with it?
(please note that they aren't touching, and cannot).

in the picture i show an example.
if i move tool1, number 84243. how will the employee "rafa" move with it.
this happens to a lot of tools so manual work is like...crazy long.
(i dont know if this is a VBA question so just in case im adding the tag.plz font be mad)[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. Put this in a module

```
Sub Test()
Dim mycell As Range
Dim mycell2 As Range

Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate 'change sheetname to what ever you got

Set mycell = Application.InputBox( _
prompt:="Select a cell", Type:=8)
Set mycell2 = Application.InputBox( _
prompt:="Select a cell", Type:=8)


Rows(mycell.Row).Cut
Rows(mycell2.Row).Insert Shift:=xlDown

End Sub
```

Comment: no, this doesn't help. sorry. is there like a function or something that will make a cell move with another cell?